# Ruby's `File.exist?` ThreadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

I am encountering errors when I am using Ruby's `File.exist?` method in middleware.  I have no idea why.

This is the background. I am improving some old webapp which hosts around 100GB of photos and growing.  I need to replicate production environment on my computer, but I don't want to download all those files.  It would be great if app could check if given file exists in my filesystem and either serve it or redirect to production server.

I thought I could do simple rack app as middleware:

```
require 'rack/utils'

class FetchMissingPicturesMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if env["PATH_INFO"].starts_with? "/system/attachments/" && !File.exist?(Rails.root.join('public').join(env["PATH_INFO"][1..-1]))
      [307, { "Location" => "http://production.example.com" + env["PATH_INFO"] }, ""]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

However, following error is thrown (not always, for some pictures it just works):

```
[2012-11-26 14:28:12] ERROR ThreadError: thread 0x10aed55e8 tried to join itself
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:31:in `lock'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:31:in `run'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/actionpack-2.3.9/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails-2.3.9/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:47:in `call'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `each'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:41:in `call'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails-2.3.9/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:48:in `service'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p371/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rack-1.1.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
    /Users/skale/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/rails-2.3.9/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    script/server:6:in `require'
    script/server:6
```

I am surprised with this issue because it's run inside mutex provided by `Rack::Lock`.  Moving this middleware before `Rack::Lock` does not help.  After removing `File.exist?` errors are gone.  This is Ruby 1.8.7 with freshest (1.8.24) rubygems on Rails 2.3.9.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found this lighthouse ticket that seems to talk about the issue you are having : https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4565
It seems it has something to do with having `config.cache_classes` set to `false` in development. However the issue is marked as resolved for Rails 2.3.6 so it might not apply to you. Hope this can help somehow.

Comment: @Raf It applies! Thanks! Now I need a way to use this middleware with cache_classes set to false for my convenience, but your finding will help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem was bit different. The last element of the response array should be an array too.

wrong:

```
[307, { "Location" => "http://production.example.com" + env["PATH_INFO"] }, ""]
```

good:

```
[307, { "Location" => "http://production.example.com" + env["PATH_INFO"] }, []]
```